# Deploying and Installing MSI over network

Tags: powershell, windows-installer, silent

Good Afternoon,
I wrote the below to copy an msi from network location to a temp dir, and then silently install. The MSI file is 1.5gb. It has been 30 minutes and it is still copying to a single hostname, hasn't even started the install part.
Is there a more efficient way of deploying this MSI? Ideally I want to deploy it to many hostnames on the network, but if it is this slow for one - it won't be usable.
Thanks

```
$computername = Get-Content "\\server\List.txt"
$sourcefile = "\\server\package.msi"

#This section will install the software 

foreach ($computer in $computername) 

{

$destinationFolder = "\\$computer\C$\temp"

#This section will copy the $sourcefile to the $destinationfolder. If the Folder does not exist it will create it.

if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder))

{

New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory

}

Copy-Item -Path $sourcefile -Destination $destinationFolder

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock { & cmd /c "msiexec.exe /i c:\temp\package.msi" TRANSFORMS=Package.mst /q LICENSEKEY="xxx" LICENSEKEYCAPENSYS="xxx" LICENSETO="Company Name" DEFAULTPDFAPP=1 CENTRALCONFIG="C:\Installer\temp 4" CENTRALCONFIGAUTOUPDATE=1 ADDLOCAL=Core,DMContextMenu,OfficeAddins,OutlookAddin,PD3App,ShellIntegration,OCRDESKTOP,Capensys,IEPreview,ShellPreview
 }
}
```

Comment: Try speeding the copy action up by using robocopy. Something like `robocopy "\\server\share\sourcedirectory" "\\$computer\C$\Temp" "package.msi" /R:2 /W:3 /NP`

Comment: Probably faster if you invoke the copy on the remote computer. So: `Invoke-Command { Copy-item ArgumentsHere } -ComputerName`, or use is with a combination of RoboCopy.